# Cannot install ClickMaster

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, windows-registry, uninstall

I wanted to install ClickMaster on Windows 8.1 after the trial versions time ran out. The problem was, that i could not uninstall the trial through windows, so i just deleted the program folder.
After that I wanted to install the new version, but every time I try try to start the installation it gives me this error which says that another version of the program is allready on the computer.

What i have tried, is to delete the registry entry of this program and also had tuneUp utilities run over the system and clean the registry. But this did not help me and the Error keeps showing up.

Comment: Can you do a system restore? Csn you do a repair installation of the trial version?

Comment: cannot do any of this

Comment: Why? Any more information?

Comment: ive tried the repair installation, but it wont install either and the system restore would remove other significant programms

Comment: So as you have the paid version now, what does the support say?

Comment: nothing yet because i wasnt calling

Comment: What is the error message / error code? You can try [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) / Tools / Uninstall / delete entry if it still exists.

Comment: it says that the version is already installed and that i have to uninstall this one first. i have used tune up, is there a differnce to cc-cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give us a link to the ClickMaster product that you installed.

In general, you need to clean-out the old version of the product that you deleted.

If the program folder that you deleted is still in the Recycle Bin, restore it and search for any file-name that contains the string "uninstall", whether executable or script.

If there is nothing in the Recycle Bin, try to reinstall/repair the old version that you deleted, then search for an uninstaller in the program's folder.

If you cannot find an uninstaller, try to run again the installation.
Sometimes the installer gives you an option for uninstalling the product if already installed.
Some other installers have an Uninstall parameter, depending on the installer.

You can also try to use an uninstaller instead of uninstalling from the Control Panel.
For a list of such programs see [Best Free Program Uninstaller](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-program-un-installer.htm#ZSoft-Uninstaller).

If all else fails, I suggest that you install the [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/)
and search the entire hard disk for any occurrence of "ClickMaster"
(or any other name that the program identified itself with).

You can also use regedit to search for that name and delete (very carefully) any occurrence
of it. However, be aware that unless you understand exactly what you are doing here,
a mistake can cause enormous harm including making Windows non-bootable.